# QgsFillSymbol crashing QGIS [RESOLVED]

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to customize my layers from a python script. I would like to add several symbol layers to features.

```
# Creating symbol layers
symbolLayers = list()
lFill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create({
    "color" : "{r},{g},{b},255".format(r = randomized_color[0],g = randomized_color[1],b = randomized_color[2])
})
symbolLayers.append(lFill)

# Create the fill symbol
symbol = QgsFillSymbol(symbolLayers)

# Adding to the current renderer
currentLayer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
currentLayer.triggerRepaint()
```

I have at this time only one symbol layer but when it will work, i will add more symbol layers.

**It crash only when i add the symbol to the renderer. Before, it seems to work (setSymbol).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was not so hard to find. If someone need the same :

```
# Must to create from a defaultsymbol
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(currentLayer.geometryType())
symbol.deleteSymbolLayer(0)

# Create all style layers
lFill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create({
    "outline_color" : "{r},{g},{b},255".format(r = randomized_color[0],g = randomized_color[1],b = randomized_color[2]),
    "outline_width" : "1",
    "style" : "no"
})
lFill2 = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer.create({
    "outline_style" : "no",
    "color" : "{r},{g},{b},90".format(r = randomized_color[0],g = randomized_color[1],b = randomized_color[2])
})

# Add them
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(lFill)
symbol.appendSymbolLayer(lFill2)

# Create a renderer with the symbol as first parameter
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)

# Define the renderer
currentLayer.setRenderer(renderer)
```